# How do you set the root page in an AppHarbor ASP.NET MVC website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, appharbor

I'm publishing an ASP.NET Web Application (this is the default application with VS2013) and it publishes just fine.  However when I visit my application

http://someapp.apphb.com

I get the "Welcome to nginx" page.  However http://someapp.apphb.com/Home works.

Is there a setting on AppHarbor that I need to change, or do I need to make a change to my WebApp?

Comment: Have u tried in RouteConfig for changing default page?

Comment: Isn't RouteConfig only available in MVC?

Comment: I just tried an MVC app and that is doing the same thing.  And locally just the application URL _http://localhost:54110/_ routes properly to the _Home_ controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can set default document in Web config file

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <add value="index.html" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```